# help with regex in perl

Tags: perl

Can someone help me get the correct regex for this string?

```
Total                       14,928  3,967
```

I am trying to remove that line using this, but no luck:

```
shift @lines if $lines[0] =~ /^Total/;
```

Its also the last line of the output file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you might consider instead is:

```
@lines = grep !/^Total/, @lines;
```

If it is always the last line:

```
splice @lines, -1, 1 if $lines[-1] =~ /^Total/;
```

`-1` is the last element in the array.

Or, more simply, as ikegami pointed out:

```
pop @lines if $lines[-1] =~ /^Total/;
```

Comment: perfect. thank you! i also was curious how to get the last element and you got that answered too. thanks again.

Comment: `splice @lines, -1, 1` is long for `splice @lines, -1` and for `pop @lines`

Comment: Timtowtdi: `$#lines -- if $lines[-1] =~ /^Total/;`